# Dropping multilevel columns from lists of dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with multilevel columns, like the one in the following MWE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=[['a','c'],['b','d']], index=['one','two'])
df.columns.names = ['aa', 'bb']
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [267]: df
Out[267]: 
aa   a  c
bb   b  d
one  1  2
two  3  4
```

I also have a list of dictionaries like the following:

```
to_keep = [{'aa':'a', 'bb':'b'}, {'aa':'q', 'bb':'d'}]
```

What I'm looking to do:

If the multilevel column labels are in the `to_keep` list then keep them in `df`, otherwise drop them from the df.

So for `df` and `to_keep` above the resulting dataframe would look like:

```
aa   a
bb   b
one  1
two  3
```

as `{'aa':'c', 'bb':'d'}` is not contained within `to_keep`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DF` mapping the column names to it's levels of the multi-index `DF`:

```
level_df = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values.tolist(), columns=np.array(df.columns.names))
level_df
```

[image]

Create another `DF` which keeps our required mapping containing list of dicts:

```
keep = pd.DataFrame(to_keep)
keep
```

[image]

Concatenate both `DFs` row-wise:

```
df_concat = pd.concat([level_df, keep], ignore_index=True)
df_concat
```

[image]

Remove all duplicates from concatenated `DF`. Drop off the level after checking if the remaining values in the concatenated `DF` is present in `level_df`:

```
cond = df_concat[~df_concat.duplicated(keep=False)]
df.drop([tuple(x) for x in cond[cond.isin(level_df).all(axis=1)].values], axis=1)
```

[image]

Note: Here it is assumed that the keys of the dictionaries match the multi-index column names.